# how to implement datetimepicker in mvc4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

In mvc 4 I am using razor syntax for my Views. Previously I used `datepicker` and it worked just fine. Now I need to be more specific when setting some time and I need to use `dateTimePicker`. In my scripts folder I have `jquery.datetimepicker.js` but I think I am missing some reference to how to display it. In the content folder I also have my `jquery.datetimepicker.css`. Also if I create new JavaScript I am not able to use `.datetimepicker` but `.datepicker.`

EDIT: Note that I havent edit anything in my BundleConfig.cs file

So my question is how I would be able to use `.datetimepicker` when writing javascript and if thats not possible how to fix the `datetimepicker` appearance  in my View because currently is like this:

[image]

Here is my View.cshtml

```
      @model MvcTestApplication.Models.Test
    @using MvcTestApplication.Models

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestTitle)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestTitle)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestTitle)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TestDescription)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TestDescription)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TestDescription)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
               <input type="text" name="StartTime" id="datetimepicker1" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                <input type="text" name="EndTime" id="datetimepicker2" />
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AvailableFor, "Available For")
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownList("AvailableFor", String.Empty)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AvailableFor)
            </div>


            <div class="editor-field">
                @if (ViewBag.CourseNames != null )
                { 
                     @Html.DropDownList("CourseNames", String.Empty)
                }

            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")

     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
     <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution myself. As I thought I had to add the CSS reference to my webpage. To do that I had to edit first the `BundleConfig.cs` placed in `App_Start` folder. I added new Style like this:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/Jcss").Include("~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css"));
```

In my View I still keep the reference to the javascript and the script it self there and I just added one more line in my `@Section Scripts`

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/Jcss")
```

Now the script itself works fine and this is the final result.

[image]